# Nested group by based on flatten record set

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, group-by

I have the following responses from the API. How can I group them into the following structure?
[image]

```
Student[]
   - Name
   - Classes[]
      - ClassName
      - ClassId
      - ClassCategories[]
          - CategoryName
          - CategoryWeight
          - Assignments[]
             - AssignmentName
             - Score
```

I was managed to group them until the "Classes" level but unable to get the ClassCategories for each of the classes

```
 var data = (from result in results
                        group result by new { result.StudentId, result.FirstName, result.LastName, result.MiddleInitial }
                        into StudentGroup
                        select new GroupedStudent
                        {
                            StudentId = StudentGroup.Key.StudentId,
                            FullName = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", StudentGroup.Key.FirstName, StudentGroup.Key.MiddleInitial, StudentGroup.Key.LastName).Replace("  ", " "),
                            Classes = from result in results
                                   group result by new { result.ClassId, result.ClassName } into ClassGroup
                                   select new groupedClass
                                   {
                                       ClassName = ClassGroup.Key.ClassName,
                                       ClassId = ClassGroup.Key.ClassId,
                                       ClassCategories = ...
                                   })
                        }).ToList();
```

Can anyone please assists me? Thank you.

Comment: What is the type of "results"?

Comment: @jhmt: The results returned as a Generic List

Comment: Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Ok, then an instance in the results has the following properties:
ClassId, ClassName, StudentName, Grade, GradePercent, AssignmentName, Grading, Points, Score, Percent, CategoryName and CategoryWeight, doesn't it?

Comment: @jhmt Yes, but then I would like to join the "results" by Students, then each student will has his registered classes and within each class will has its class categories and each category will has its assignments. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have make ClassGroup from StudentGroup not from results.

```
Classes = from s in StudentGroup group result by new { s.ClassId, s.ClassName } into ClassGroup
```

The complete linq query is as follows:

```
    var data =
        (from result in results
         group result by new { result.StudentId, result.FirstName, result.LastName, result.MiddleInitial } into StudentGroup
         select new
         {
             StudentId = StudentGroup.Key.StudentId,
             FullName = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", StudentGroup.Key.FirstName, StudentGroup.Key.MiddleInitial, StudentGroup.Key.LastName).Replace("  ", " "),
             Classes = (from s in StudentGroup
                        group s by new { s.ClassId, s.ClassName } into ClassGroup
                        select new
                        {
                            ClassId = ClassGroup.Key.ClassId,
                            ClassName = ClassGroup.Key.ClassName,
                            ClassCategories = (from c in ClassGroup
                                               group c by new { c.CategoryName, c.CategoryWeight } into CategoryGroup
                                               select new
                                               {
                                                   CategoryName = CategoryGroup.Key.CategoryName,
                                                   CategoryWeight = CategoryGroup.Key.CategoryWeight,
                                                   Assignments = (from ct in CategoryGroup
                                                                  group ct by new { ct.AssignmentName, ct.Score } into AssingnmentGroup
                                                                  select new
                                                                  {
                                                                      AssignmentName = AssingnmentGroup.Key.AssignmentName,
                                                                      Score = AssingnmentGroup.Key.Score
                                                                  }).ToList()
                                               }).ToList()
                        }).ToList()
         }).ToList();
```

For example, if you want to access to the first Assignment's score, you can get it like this:

```
var student = data.FirstOrDefault();
var score = student.Classes[0].ClassCategories[0].Assignments[0].Score;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I get this sorted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is usually how I do It.

- Create a class to store your data
- Create a list of that class type
- In your case instead of `string dataRow` maybe you can use a sub class

.

```
// get data from webservice
var json = webClient.DownloadString(url);
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json);

// create a list to save all the element
List<myClass> classList = new List<myClass>();

// process every row
foreach (string dataRow in values)
{
  string[] dataField = dataRow.Split(',');

  // have a constructor to assign each value to this element
  myClass ctROW = new myClass(dataField);
  classList.add(ctROW );
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, not sure if this is a good practice as I might have a lot of duplicated ClassId from my results set.

Comment: Im saying how I do it. I dont get duplicated data. Of curse this is just a general idea. But after doing `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json);` you should have a very good idea of what do next.

Comment: If this doesnt work for you let me know and I will delete my answer. Dont know why someone make a downvote wihout leave a comment.

Comment: Calos Oropeze I tried and this is working, but I prefer to using linq to do it though. Thanks again.